# unique_together in Table with ForeignKey pointing to itself

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Table described:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Lets assume that we have two parents:

Table(id=1, name="first")
Table(id=2, name="second")

When I create children:

Table(name="first", parent=1)
Table(name="first", parent=2)

save objects should pass, but when I enter again and save

Table(name="first_child", parent=1)

it should fail. How can I do it? Unique in name is not a solution because parent and child can have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comment

```
unique_together = ('name', 'parent')
```

was good way, bu it was only part of solution. I also made clean function with such code:

```
    if self.parent is None:
        try:
            result = Table.objects.filter(name=self.name, parent=None)
            if result.count():
                raise
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ValidationError('Record with this name already exists')
```

This part checked if there is no such record without parent. So it works like unique but only for records without parent.

Answer (score 2):

Use `unique=True`, or a `OnetoOneKey`, instead of the `ForeignKey`. Refer the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield).